# How to send POST request from Postman to mongodb in Digital Ocean cloud server?

Tags: postman, digital-ocean, postman-pre-request-script

I was able to login my MERN stack application locally when I ran in my laptop, but when I deployed to the digital ocean droplet server, all of my existing database inside MongoDB had been deleted, so as of now I am not able to login into my application in cloud server, the question is how can I send POST request from Postman to MongoDB that I deployed in cloud server so that I can register new user and able to login into system? Thank you.

Below POST request should be sent from the Postman but it's not able to send to the cloud:

```
{{droplet_url}}/api/user/register
```

Comment: Could you please add in the error that you are getting after hitting the above URL from postman? Also, I hope you have deployed a MongoDB instance as well in your droplet.

Comment: Thank you for your comment amanpurohit, now I able to connect with it, there is some technical error.